# Laravel 5: constants.php vs constants in controller vs constants in model

Tags: php, laravel, constants

I'm using `Laravel 5` and I need to add some immutable values (constants) to be able to make use of them in controllers mostly (maybe in views too). Question is: What's the best approach?

I've been reading and 90% of approaches suggest to use a `constants.php` and `Config.get()`, but I don't like this because (I think) a constant is not a config value. I mean, it's not supposed to be changed. In other frameworks, I like to use models or other lib class to define values related to the entity I'm working on, Eg.: I need a constant for cache time in users, then `User::CACHE_1_DAY = '86400'` (silly example btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding a new class containing Helper methods, and bind that class to the application in your `AppServiceProvider`.
Finally inside that class, place getter methods for the constants.

Comment: Thanks. It's a valid approach I guess.